# Laravel migration: integrity constraint violation

Tags: laravel, migration, constraints

I get an error whenever I try to insert values into this table.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
> update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`usersexam`.`role_user`, CONSTRAINT `role_user_role_id_foreign`
> FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Here is the migration for that table in my Laravel's database folder:

```
class CreateRoleUserPivotTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')
            ->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->cascadeOnDelete();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('role_user');
    }
}
```

So I am inserting it into two columns. What is wrong with the table?

UPDATE: here is my insert query

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you also show your insert query?

Comment: Could you please update your post with the insert operation code?

Comment: updated with the insert query

Answer (score 0):

when ever ur creating a tables and refrense a foreign key u still need to make the columns so instead of

```
Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->cascadeOnDelete();
    });
```

it should be something like

```
 Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('role_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');

        $table->foreign('role_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('roles')
            ->cascadeOnDelete();
    
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->cascadeOnDelete();
    });
```

Comment: This is no longer the case. In recent versions of Laravel you can simply do `$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete()` to achieve the same thing. See here: https://laravel.com/docs/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: Tried this, I am still getting the same error